# What is this series about people working in a mining cave hallucinating and going mad after seeing tiny feet?

Tags: story-identification, tv

I can't remember too much about this series. It was either late 70's, or early 80's.  All I can remember was that there were people working for a mining company and people started to go crazy (or died) after hallucinating or actually seeing something within the cave. Just before this happened we (the audience) saw something like tiny dwarf feet, leading (I think) to some sort of light.

The only other information I can remember is that this show came on after Dr. Who (Tom Baker era,) but I don't know if it was on the same channel.

It's a long shot I know, but I was wondering if anybody else remembers this series or what it was called.

Comment: What country were you in at the time, and in particular, do you remember what TV channel you were watching?

Comment: Some similarities to the Paul Ernst short story, "The Microscopic Giants", from 1936. Miners working deep in the earth encounter tiny but incredibly dense humanoids from deeper within the earth. I don't know if this story was ever made into a film. Was this series a continuing story, or an anthology?

Comment: "Came on after Doctor Who" on BBC, or in the US on PBS or... They would have aired at different times and had different schedules.\